# ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer resnet50: expected shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), found shape=(6, 13)

Tags: python, keras, resnet

I'm would like to use Keras and build a Resnet model but I'm just using a one-dimensional data with 13 features. I got this error after a few unsuccessful attempts, and I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions? Thank you very much!

if it helps, here's some of my code...

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy import ndimage
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50

model = ResNet50(weights=None,classes=2)

model.compile(optimizer="adam",loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

y = df['Label']
X = df.drop('Label',axis=1)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 101)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

model.fit(X_train,y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=6)
```

Comment: No, you can not use that Resnet with 1D data.

Comment: hi, so it is that i cannot apply ResNet on any 1D data?

Comment: That's not how it works. ResNet50 pretrained model contains 2D convolutions which do not suit your data, you can create your residual network using 1D convolutions.

Comment: Yes. Resnet builds for image tasks, you could try to build a model with `dense layer`.